# Does µTorrent v2 have a security vulnerability?

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

Many people are using a second version of µTorrent because they don't like the ads (even though one can disable ads on v3).

It is generally recommended to update software because of potential security vulnerabilities that are fixed over time.

Are there any known vulnerabilities in µTorrent v2 that have been fixed in v3? If so, what are they?

Comment: There's two more sensible options here - firstly to turn off ads, and using the newer versions, or secondly, do what I did, and vote with my feet by switching clients. There's almost never a good reason to use an old version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can never be sure if there are no security vulnerabilities, but a quick search through a [version history of µTorrent](http://www.afterdawn.com/software/version_history.cfm/utorrent) doesn't show me any fixed security issues in 3.0+.

Comment: A version history requires somebody to keep track of every single change, document the change, and then describe it.  Its not unheard of that secruity problems are simply resolved and never properly documented in these types of projects.  I go the simple approach just disable the ads or switch clients.

Answer (score 2):

Here is [a list of µTorrent vulnerabilities from the CVE database](http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-6117/Utorrent.html).  Skimming through, I can see at least one ([CVE-2010-3129](http://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2010-3129/)) affecting versions up to 2.0.3.

Comment: upvoted; sorry i didnt pick this answer, but it was a coin toss.